# Remove duplicate on multiple columns keep newest

Tags: python, r, date, duplicates

I would like to get following result using R and/or Python:

IF `CoordinateX` AND `CoordinateY` AND `Name` are the same THEN keep the newest `Date`.

[image: My Data]

I have some issues with my loop in python.

Comment: Post a code chunk. What have you tried so far? Avoid, screen shot, please.

Comment: "I have some issues with my loop" - that is a shame, we can't help if we can't see it though. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, using `dplyr`:

```
data %>% 
    group_by(Name, CoordinateX, CoordinateY) %>% 
    arrange(desc(Date)) %>% 
    distinct() %>% 
    ungroup()
```

Give the output:

```
Name       Date CoordinateX CoordinateY
Aaa  2018-08-29      650000      134999
Bbb  2010-08-29      650000      134999
Bbb  2010-08-29      655600      134999
Ccc  2010-08-29      655600      134999
```